# GitHub Pages: "bundle exec jekyll serve" freezes on "Generating..."

Tags: git, rubygems, bundler, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I am using GitHub Pages Jekyll with the bootstrap theme, "Feeling Responsive." My issue is that the jekyll bundler freezes in the middle of generating.

To develop the jekyll site locally, I run "bundle exec jekyll serve" instead of "jekyll serve" because I get this error,

```
J-MacBook-Pro:<user>.github.io jimbo$ jekyll serve
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.13.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:40:in     
`block in setup': You have already activated colorator 1.1.0, but your Gemfile     
requires colorator 0.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve 
this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

All was working well until one day I ran, "bundle exec jekyll serve", as usual, and it froze. Now, every time I run the command, it freezes.

What I have tried so far:

1. git reset to a previous commit when all was working well.
2. restart terminal and editor.
3. restart mac.

So far, nothing works and this is what I see whenever I run the build:

```
J-MacBook-Pro:<user>.github.io jimbo$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file:    
/Users/jimbo/Dropbox/Github/<user>.github.io/_config.yml
   Source: /Users/jimbot/Dropbox/Github/<user>.github.io
   Destination: /Users/jimbo/Dropbox/Github/<user>.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
  Generating...
```

It would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction here. Mainly, why would generating freeze in this fashion and what can I do to fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you point us to your repository? Have you tried getting a minimal site working?

Comment: Wondering if the copy of the build log has an error. Otherwise, why does `source` have the username `jimbot` while `destination` has the username `jimbo`

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue after adding the jekyll-press plugin to my Gemfile. I just removed it from my Gemfile, ran `bundle` and the issue was resolved.